# Salta la opción del Menú

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
¿Por qué no me llama el menú cuando ejecuto el script?


    eng = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:11111@localhost:3307/Nomina_jul15", echo=False)

    def Menu():  
             menu = textwrap.dedent('''\
                    Estas en el Menu Principal de Empleados

                      1. Agregar    Empleado
                      2. Modificar  Empleado
                      3. Eliminar   Empleado
                      4. Ver        Empleados
                      5. Salir del Menu Empleados
                    ''')
        while True:
            os.system('cls')
            print(menu)
            OP = input("Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada: ")

            if not OP.isdigit():
                os.system('cls')
                print("Esto no es un numero por favor elija uno!!!!\n")
            elif OP == '1':
                Agregar()
            elif OP == '2':
                Modificar()
            elif OP == '3':
                Eliminar()
            elif OP == '4':
                Ver()
            elif OP == '5':
                Salir()
                break
            else:
                os.system('cls')
                print("Por favor, digite un numero del menu!!!\n")

    def Agregar():
        print("Estas en la Opcion Agregar Empleados ")


    Session = sessionmaker(bind=eng)
    session = Session()

    idEmpleados = 0
    numdocEmp = input("Digite el numero de Documento del Empleado")
    nombreEmp = input("Digite el nombre del empleado")
    salbasicEmp = input("Digite el salario basico mes del empleado")
    fechaingEmp = input("Digite la fecha de ingreso del empleado")
    nombre_eps = input("Digite el nombre de La EPS")
    nombre_afp = input("Digite el nombre de la AFP")
    fechanacEmp = input("Digite la Fecha de nacimiento del Empleado")
    sexoEmp = input("Digite el sexo del Empleado (F) o (M) ")

    e = (idEmpleados, numdocEmp, nombreEmp, salbasicEmp, fechaingEmp, nombre_eps, nombre_afp, fechanacEmp, sexoEmp)

    os.system('cls')

    session.execute("insert into Empleados values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", e)

    session.commit()
    eng.close()  



    def Ver():

        connection = eng.connect()

        Session = sessionmaker (bind=eng)
        session = Session()

        print("Estas en la Opcion Ver Empleados ")
        print("")
        print("idEmpleados \t numdocEmp  \t nombreEmp \t salbasicEmp \t fechaingEmp \t nombre_eps \t nombre_afp \t fechanacEmp \t sexoEmp")
        print("============================================================================================================================")

        meta = MetaData(eng)
        empleados = Table('empleados', meta, autoload=True)

        rs = session.query(empleados)

        for i in rs:
            print(i)


Salta a la función ingresar y no entiendo porque, se salta el Menu: 

> C:\Python35\python.exe C:/Python35/PROYECTOS-PYTHON35/Curso-SqlALchemy/empleadoSqlalchemy.py    

>Digite el numero de Documento del Empleado
```

Comment: Jsierra hola de nuevo, te vuelvo a repetir lo mismo que en otras preguntas... formatea el código por favor. Selecciona el código en tu editor, lo copias y lo pegas aquí, lo seleccionas todo y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k`  o el botón `{}` del editor. Para poder ayudar tenemos que ver el código **exactamente igual** que está en tu `.py`, con la misma identación. Python determina los bloques de código por la identación, no es algo trivial, es básico. Que una línea esté o no identada significa que está o no dentro de una función por ejemplo...

Comment: ok, entendido, no sabia como formatearlo.

Comment: Disculpa, no le habia puesto el cuidado suficiente.

Comment: No te preocupes, es que sin ver el código tal y como lo tienes es imposible señalar posibles errores. Voy a responderte a ver si llegamos a algo.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Jsiera una pregunta,¿El bloque de código que va desde `Session = sessionmaker...` hasta `eng.close` lo tienes así, fuera de la función `Agregar` (identado al mimo nivel que `def Agregar()`)?

Comment: Si, claro asi lo tengo identado a nivel de la funcion?

Comment: FJSevilla, Gracias ese el problema, ya lo aregle, la identacion no estaba acorde.

Comment: Tengo otra duda, con sola conexion al motor puedo ejecutar las demas funciones en mi caso son cinco; (ingresar, modificar, eliminar, ver y salir)?

Comment: una sola conexion al motor(engine)

Comment: Es posible hacer eso?

Comment: Para hacer eso tienes que crear la conexión fuera de las funciones, como variable global o dentro de `Menu` y pasar la conexión como argumento al resto de las funciones (pasar `sesion` por ejemplo). Yo haría lo segundo, cerrando la conexión al salir de `Menu`.

Comment: Entiendo, creo que lo he visto en algunos codigos ejemplo con SqlAlchemy

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65442/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-jsierra2017).